# JSON text field with quotes

Tags: python, json

So I have some JSON text fields with quotes in it. And when I try to extract the value of the field using the following code it gives me error if the text field contains quotes in it.

```
filename="op.json"

fp=open(filename, "r")
wp=open("new.json", "w")

json_object = json.load(fp)

for tweet in json_object["ABC"]:
        wp.write ("\" created at \": \"" + str(tweet["created_at"]) + "\"")
        wp.write ("\" id \": \"" + str(tweet["id"]) + "\"")
```

It will work fine for the input  `"id": "This is the id"`

But won't work for `"id": This "is" the id"`

Comment: Where's the comma in the text fields that you give as example?

Comment: You appear to be confusing commas (`,`) with quotation marks (`"`), sometimes informally referred to as "inverted commas".

Comment: Well, `"id": This "is" the id"` is not valid JSON. Can please post an example of the actual JSON you have? If the JSON is not valid, then you have to fix whatever generates it.

Comment: Let's also see your file, the first few lines, please. I am unable to support you without more data.

Comment: {{
  "statuses": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "result_type": "popular",
        "iso_language_code": "en"
      },
      "created_at": "Sat Sep 12 20:39:47 +0000 2015",
      "id": 642799790649159700,
      "id_str": "642799790649159684",
      "text": "Great atmosphere, great team spirit, great win  http://t.co/PYexs8j6tN",
      "source": "<a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>",
      "truncated": false,                                                                                  these are the first few lines of my tweet file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second example is not correct JSON. If you have double quotes inside a string, they need to be escaped with backslash:

```
{ "ABC": [
    { "id1": "This is the id" },
    { "id2": "This \"is\" the id" }
    ]
}
```

You need to fix whatever program is creating the JSON file so it creates proper format. I suspect it's not using a library function, so it doesn't handle special cases like this. Use a JSON library and it should work well.